# registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.CaptureVideo()) callback is always false

Tags: android, kotlin, android-contentresolver

I provided Uri with **contentResolver** on version>29
The ActivityResultContracts.takePicture() works well.
I used the Uri to capture video with the following code

```
private val getVideo =
    registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.CaptureVideo()) { result ->
        if (result) {
            // Always false
        }
    }
```

Then in the method

```
getVideo.launch(uri)
```

The method works well, and the video is saved correctly in the provided Uri, but the callback result is always false.

Edit:
I found out what the problem is. The callback is called before video writing is over. It seems the CaptureVideo() bug. It could be handled with some delay but this isn't clean. I'm searching for receiving a callback after the video write is finished.

Comment: How does one provide an uri with content resolver?

Comment: contentResolver.insert()

Comment: In what did you insert what?

Comment: I created a ContentValues() and insert it by contentResolver.insert().
The output is a Uri.
I'm using this method for creating file URI for upper Q

Comment: You stil did not tell in what you inserted the stuff. And what stuff? Where did you get the uri from?